# Can't list or restore elasticseach snapshots with azure plugin

Tags: azure, elasticsearch

I've elasticsearch cluster deployed on azure and I'm using azure repository plugin to store my snapshots and backups there. this was working very properly but out of the sudden I can't list or restore anything now. I can't even see logs or something that can guide me.
Do you have any solution for this ??

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue .. after a long time of troubleshooting we found that the issue is from azure load balancer which is basic tier. I changed it to be standard and it worked.